# Inverted page table size

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

Certain computer with paged virtual memory has 4KB pages, a 32 bit byte addressable virtual address space and 30 bit byte addressable physical address space. The system manages an inverted page table. Where each entry includes page number plus 12 overhead bits.
What is size of basic inverted page table including page number and overhead bits is?

My attempt:
I can deduce that if logical address is p+d and physical address is f+d then 
p=20,d=12,f=18

After this I am lost. I reffered to other similar questions but this virtal and physical addressing is confusing.Plz guide.

**EDIT: my new question is : is the formula for page size is= no. Of pages in virtual memory × f ,OR , is it no. Of pages in main memory × (p+d)????**

Comment: size of basic inverted page table including page number and overhead bits is 116KB

Comment: There is insufficient information in the question to give a correct answer.  I am puzzled what the source of such repeated questions with no answer comes from.

Comment: Just clarify the exact formula for page size. Thats all I asked